# Installable units are missing in p2 repository, so that tycho-p2-director fails when setting source=repository

Tags: tycho, p2

I am building a product (in an eclipse-repository module) containing several features which configure their plug-ins via installable units created through p2.inf files.

This works as long as I use the default value `targetPlatform` for the `source` configuration parameter of the [tycho-p2-director-plugin](http://eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-director-plugin/materialize-products-mojo.html). AFAIK this makes the director access the p2 metadata from `<project_dir>/target/targetPlatformRepository/context.xml` and the artifacts from the local Maven repository.

As I want to modify some bundles, I changed the `source` parameter to `repository`. This makes the director use artifacts and metadata from the generated repository in `<project_dir>/target/repository` and breaks my build ;-)

It seems that the installable units created via the p2.inf are missing in `<project_dir>/target/repository/content.jar` whereas `<project_dir>/target/targetPlatformRepository/context.xml` is complete. E.g. the following unit is only contained in the latter:

```
<unit id='configure.org.sample.bundle' ...>
  <!-- config -->
</unit>
```

How do I configure the build to also include that installable unit in `project/repository/content.jar`?

Here is a snippet of my p2.inf file:

```
# org.sample.bundle
requires.0.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
requires.0.name=configure.org.sample.bundle
requires.0.greedy=true

units.0.id=configure.org.sample.bundle
units.0.version=1.0.0
units.0.provides.1.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu
units.0.provides.1.name=configure.org.sample.bundle
units.0.provides.1.version=1.0.0
units.0.instructions.install=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.installBundle(bundle:${artifact});
units.0.instructions.configure=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.setStartLevel(startLevel:2); org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.markStarted(started:true);
units.0.hostRequirements.1.namespace=osgi.bundle
units.0.hostRequirements.1.name=org.sample.bundle
units.0.hostRequirements.1.greedy=false
units.0.hostRequirements.2.namespace=org.eclipse.equinox.p2.eclipse.type
units.0.hostRequirements.2.name=bundle
units.0.hostRequirements.2.range=[1.0.0,2.0.0)
units.0.hostRequirements.2.greedy=false
units.0.requires.1.namespace=osgi.bundle
units.0.requires.1.name=org.sample.bundle
units.0.requires.1.greedy=false
```

And the error from Tycho build:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: sample 1.0.0.201308060715 (sample.product 1.0.0.201308060715)
Missing requirement: Sample Feature 1.0.0.201308060715 (sample.feature.feature.group
1.0.0.201308060715) requires 'configure.org.sample.bundle 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: "As I want to modify some bundles..." - This seems wrong. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but using `source=repository` to modify bundles outside of their module build is not a proper solution.

Comment: First of all thank you for responding to my question again :-).

The modification just consists of signing the bundles. So i guess this is not smelling that strong than you thought initially. Any idea why the Installable Units are incomplete in the generated p2 repository?

Comment: Did you change your [project.build.directory](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) to `project`? Usually the paths are `target/repository/`, `target/targetPlatformRepository/`, ...

Comment: Sorry my fault, i just meant <project_dir>/target/...
Edited the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a product installation, the p2 director needs to resolve all transitve dependencies of the product. However by default, the p2 repository built in an eclipse-repository module (usually at `target/repository/`) only aggregates the included content.

Since you are saying that the units created via the p2.inf are missing in the `target/repository/` p2 repository, they are probably not included in the features but only referenced as dependency. Although you could also change the p2.inf to generate inclusions, this is probably not the easiest solution.

Instead, simply configure the [tycho-p2-repository-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-repository-plugin/assemble-repository-mojo.html) to aggregate not only inclusions but all dependencies:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, it shouldn't matter if you have the [tycho-p2-director-plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-director-plugin/materialize-products-mojo.html) install directly from the target platform or from the aggregated p2 repository.

Comment: If this wasn't it, I'd need the error message of the failing build.

Comment: You p2.inf looks okay, so `includeAllDependencies=true` should pull the configure.org.sample.bundle into the build result repository. Could you try again with `mvn clean verify -Dtycho.localArtifacts=ignore` (to ensure that the problem isn't caused by locally installed artifacts)? If this doesn't help, there might be a [bug in Tycho](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho). (Please attach your sample project when reporting a bug.)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Executing the build with the given property leads to the same fault. I am trying to set up a small sample build and going to report the bug during the day.

Comment: You need to configure `includeAllDependencies=true` in the module that contains the product. Then it works.

Comment: Indeed works like a charm with the right configuration. Didn't get the point to configure the product to include all dependencies. So many pitfalls to jump into - thanks for helping me out.